# java - List remove specific object base on object property

Tags: java

> Supposed I have a list of objects

```
[
    Post(postid=1, title=testtitle1, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
    Post(postid=2, title=testtitle2, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
    Post(postid=4, title=testtitle4, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
]
```

> and I have an incoming request like this:

```
[
    Post(postid=4, title=zzzzzzz, post=testpost, created_at=null, updated_at=null)
]
```

How can I replace the old post with `post id 4`

```
Post(postid=4, title=testtitle4, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
```

with the new request

```
[
    Post(postid=4, title=zzzzzzz, post=testpost, created_at=null, updated_at=null)
]
```

so that the list will become like this

```
[
    Post(postid=1, title=testtitle1, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
    Post(postid=2, title=testtitle2, post=test, created_at=null, updated_at=null),
    Post(postid=4, title=zzzzzzz, post=testpost, created_at=null, updated_at=null)
]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Doesn't look like an array of objects, but you can always iterate and have a check on the ```postid = 4``` in an ```if```block and do the replacement of fields accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, one of them is :

```
posts.removeIf(p -> Objects.equals(newPost().getId(), p.getId()));
posts.add(newPost);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Map data structure for your usecase, instead of using list:

Write code like below:

```
public class PostBase {
         private Map<Integer,Post> posts = new HashMap();   

           public void addPost(Post post) {
                posts.put(post.getPostid(), post);
            }

          public Post getPost(int id){
                return posts.get(id);
          }
}
```

If you still want to use list, you can remove existing element by find element by id and add new one like below(similar to answered by YCF_L):

```
Post newpost = new Post(4, "xxx", "tt", null, null);
postlist.removeIf((post)->post.getPostid() == newpost.getPostid());
postlist.add(newpost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
for(Post post : posts) {
    if(idOfIncomingRequest.equals(post.postid)) {
        // update your data here
    }
}
```